OrderQuantity field in line items being returned by Azure Document Intelligence for Prebuild Invoice Model
I am using version 3.0 of the Forms recognizer API with the prebuilt-invoice model to scan documents. The vast majority of the invoices return a "Quantity" field when line items have quantities. However, we have begun seeing line item data with "OrderQuantity" in the JSON.
The documentation does not list OrderQuantity as a line item field in the concepts or GetAnalyzeResult API documentation. I tried the 4.0 preview API as well and got the same results. My question is are there any more other undocumented fields or synonyms we must account for in the code consuming this API?

It is possible that OrderQuantity is a custom field that was added by the invoice issuer and is not part of the prebuilt model.
